# Pause video and toggle button

Tags: javascript, video

The code snippet provided by this site doesn't work perfectly.  I suspect I've missed something when copying and pasting from my page.  But I hope it's enough for someone to give me direction on what I need to do.

- I load a video file
- I play the video
- Another function calculates and sets a variable nextVeh
- When the video playback time (currentTime) exceeds the nextVeh value then I want to pause the video and toggle the play button to show paused

**How do I do this from within the duringPlayback function?**  I'm not figuring it out.  I'd sure appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

```js
if (video.canPlayType) {   // tests that we have HTML5 video support
  //  play video
  function vidplay(evt) {
    if (video.src == "") {  // inital source load
      getVideo();
    }
    button = evt.target; //  get the button id to swap the text based on the state                                    
    if (video.paused) {   // play the file, and display pause symbol
      video.play();
      button.textContent = "||";
    } else {              // pause the file, and display play symbol  
      video.pause();
      button.textContent = ">";
    }
  }
//  load video file from input field
  function getVideo() {
    var fileURL = document.getElementById("videoFile").value;  // get input field                    
    if (fileURL != "") {
      video.src = fileURL;
      video.load();  // if HTML source element is used
      //document.getElementById("btn_play").click();  // start play
      video.controls = false; //defaults display of video controls to off
    } else {
      errMessage("Enter a valid video URL");  // fail silently
    }
  }
}

//  Play
document.getElementById("btn_play").addEventListener("click", vidplay, false);

var nextVeh;
nextVeh = 10; // this is normally set in another function
function duringPlayback() {
  document.getElementById("elapsed").innerHTML = (Math.round(video.currentTime * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
  if (video.currentTime > nextVeh) {
    document.getElementById("btn_play").click();
    // not understanding what to do here to pause video and toggle the button to paused
  }
};
```

```html
<span>Enter a video URL<br />
  <button id="btn_loadVideo" style="float: left" title="Load video button">Load</button>
  <label for:"videoFile">
    <input type="text" id="videoFile" style="width: 400px;" title="video file input field" />
  </label>
</span>
<div>
  <div>
    <video id="video" class="left" controls style="border: 1px solid blue;" height="240" width="320" title="video element"></video>
    <br />
    <button id="btn_play" title="Play">&gt;</button>
    <span>Playback position: <span id="elapsed"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `video.pause()` will pause the video ? Did you try just calling the `vidplay` function instead of triggering an event.

Comment: Yes.  Just calling vidplay doesn't do anything.  (That was my first thought and I still don't know why it doesn't work.)  video.pause does pause the video, but it both disables use of the play/pause button and puts the symbol on the button out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!  Simple.  I just tried guessing.  As I mentioned earlier, video.pause successfully paused the video.  But it gets the play/pause button out of sync and that causes problems with the event button working properly.  I didn't think that changing the button.textContent outside the canPlayType and vidplay would function, but it does! (I don't understand how/why, but I'll take it.) I don't even have to call the elementId for the button.  (Again, I don't understand how/why, but I'll take it).

```
if (video.currentTime > nextVeh) {
        console.log("currentTime > nextVeh");
        video.pause();            //THIS WORKS!
        button.textContent = ">"; //THIS WORKS!
        // do more stuff
    } else {
        // do something
        console.log("currentTime < nextVeh");
    }
```